# IDEA maven goal returns 'Process finished with exit code 1'

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, ninja

in Eclipse I do this :

[image: Eclipse run configurations]

and it works :

[image: Console output]

but in IDEA :

[image: IDEA run configurations]

all I get is this :

[image: No console output]

I don't understand why it's not launching correctly.

---

I've done the same in Eclipse and IDEA :

1. Created project with

> ```
> mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeGroupId=org.ninjaframework -DarchetypeArtifactId=ninja-servlet-jpa-blog-archetype
>
> cd MY_INSTALLED_PROJECT
> mvn clean install
> mvn ninja:run
> ```

2. And finally, imported project as a Maven project

And now I'm clueless. Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Update : 2018-01-30, still haven't found the solution!

Answer (score 1):

I don't have an answer, but did narrow down the problem. Seems the combination of using Maven 3.5.x (I tested with 3.5.0 and 3.5.2) with JIdea. Here's the command line generated by JIdea to perform "clean" lifecycle:

```
C:\Dev\GitHub\cas-server>C:\Dev\JavaTools\jdk1.8.0_131\bin\java -Dmaven.home=C:\Dev\JavaTools\apache-maven-3.5.2 -Dclassworlds.conf=C:\Dev\JavaTools\apache-maven-3.2.1\bin\m2.
conf -Didea.launcher.port=7535 "-Didea.launcher.bin.path=C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 13.1.5\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\Dev\JavaTools\apache-maven-3.2.1\boot\plexus-classworlds-2.5.1.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 13.1.5\lib\idea_rt.jar" com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher -Didea.version=13.1.5 -X clean
```

Here I changed just the maven.home to point to Maven 3.2.1 folder, but left all other maven path references pointing at Maven 3.5.2. That works:

```
C:\Dev\GitHub\cas-server>C:\Dev\JavaTools\jdk1.8.0_131\bin\java -Dmaven.home=C:\Dev\JavaTools\apache-maven-3.2.1 -Dclassworlds.conf=C:\Dev\JavaTools\apache-maven-3.5.2\bin\m2.conf -Didea.launcher.port=7534 "-Didea.launcher.bin.path=C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 13.1.5\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\Dev\JavaTools\apache-maven-3.5.2\boot\plexus-classworlds-2.5.2.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 13.1.5\lib\idea_rt.jar" com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher -Didea.version=13.1.5 clean
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] Using the builder org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder with a thread count of 1
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building cas-overlay 1.0
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ cas-overlay ---
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.390 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-02-26T15:12:06-05:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 6M/123M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

Add flag

> -X

It's verbose mode.

And check maven settings (settings.xml) in Intellij IDEA.

> Preferences / Maven / User Settings file

Comment: Connected to the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:9492', transport: 'socket'
Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:9492', transport: 'socket'


Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: Can you run without IDE (in console)? What is result?

Comment: Ok, which is a value of "maven home directory"? is it variables equals Eclipse and IDEA? Does it same?